# JIRA development - creating a screen (FieldScreen) programmatically

Tags: java, jira

I'm pretty new to JIRA and I'm currently working on integrating my JIRA plugin with the JIRA issue tracking system. My plan is to create a couple of custom fields and then create a custom screen (FieldScreen) that will contain these fields. I've created one custom field but I'm having trouble with creating the screen.

```
// Create issue type:
IssueType myIssueType = this.issueTypeManager.createIssueType("FOO", "FOOBAR", "/images/icons/issuetypes/genericissue.png");

// Create custom field:
// Create a list of issue types for which the custom field needs to be available    
List<GenericValue> issueTypes = new ArrayList<GenericValue>();
issueTypes.add(myIssueType.getGenericValue());

// Create a list of project contexts for which the custom field needs to be available
List<JiraContextNode> contexts = new ArrayList<JiraContextNode>();
contexts.add(GlobalIssueContext.getInstance());

CustomFieldType fieldType = this.customFieldManager.getCustomFieldType("com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:textfield");
CustomFieldSearcher fieldSearcher = this.customFieldManager.getCustomFieldSearcher("com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:textsearcher");
CustomField cField = this.customFieldManager.createCustomField("Basic Text Field", "This is a basic text field", fieldType, fieldSearcher, contexts, issueTypes);

/* 
    Change this next part, instead of adding to the default screen:
    1) Create a new screen (FieldScreen)
    2) Add the custom field (cField) to that screen
*/

// Add field to default Screen
FieldScreen defaultScreen = fieldScreenManager.getFieldScreen(FieldScreen.DEFAULT_SCREEN_ID);
if (!defaultScreen.containsField(cField.getId())) {
    FieldScreenTab firstTab = defaultScreen.getTab(0);
    firstTab.addFieldScreenLayoutItem(cField.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out how to do this:

1) I needed to uncomment a dependency in the pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

2) I looked at this this post here:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/9390368/adding-field-screens-programatically-in-a-plugin